# WSO2 IS / AGW update challenge questions only updating "admin" account

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 IS 5.0.0 / API Manager 1.9.1.  We created a Rest API to handle the call for the internal WSO2 soap call setChallengeQuestionsOfUser in the UserIdentityManagementAdminService, however when we call this method with a specific userName the method will always update the Admin account.

Here is a code we are using to invoke the soap service

```
<resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/updatechallengequestionofuser" faultSequence="fault">    <!-- Only Updating admin --> 
      <inSequence>
         <class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.mediators.TokenPasser"/>
         <property name="USERNAME" expression="//userName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="USERANSWER1" expression="//userAnswer1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="QUESTIONSETID1" expression="//questionSetId1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="QUESTIONTEXT1" expression="//questionText1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="USERANSWER2" expression="//userAnswer2" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="QUESTIONSETID2" expression="//questionSetId2" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="QUESTIONTEXT2" expression="//questionText2" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="USERANSWER3" expression="//userAnswer3" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="QUESTIONSETID3" expression="//questionSetId3" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="QUESTIONTEXT3" expression="//questionText3" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>              
                  <ser:setChallengeQuestionsOfUser xmlns:ser="http://services.mgt.identity.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:xsd="http://dto.mgt.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
                    <ser:userName>$1</ser:userName>
                    <ser:challengesDTOs>            
                        <xsd:answer>$2</xsd:answer>                     
                        <xsd:id>$3</xsd:id>
                        <xsd:question>$4</xsd:question>
                    </ser:challengesDTOs>
                    <ser:challengesDTOs>            
                        <xsd:answer>$5</xsd:answer>
                        <xsd:id>$6</xsd:id>
                        <xsd:question>$7</xsd:question>
                    </ser:challengesDTOs>
                    <ser:challengesDTOs>            
                        <xsd:answer>$8</xsd:answer>
                        <xsd:id>$9</xsd:id>
                        <xsd:question>$10</xsd:question>
                    </ser:challengesDTOs>
                </ser:setChallengeQuestionsOfUser>  
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('USERNAME')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('USERANSWER1')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('QUESTIONSETID1')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('QUESTIONTEXT1')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('USERANSWER2')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('QUESTIONSETID2')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('QUESTIONTEXT2')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('USERANSWER3')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('QUESTIONSETID3')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('QUESTIONTEXT3')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:setChallengeQuestionsOfUser"/>
         <property name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', '<base64String>')" scope="transport"/>        
         <property name="Accept" expression="text/xml" scope="transport"/>
         <property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"></property>
         <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"></property>

         <send>
            <endpoint name="UserManagement_APIproductionEndpoint_4">
               <address uri="https://wso2dev.comp.org/services/UserIdentityManagementAdminService" format="soap11">
               </address>
            </endpoint>
         </send> 
     </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler"/>
         <property name="ContentType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"></property>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"></property>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
```

There are no error messages in the wso2carbon.log file but we see that only the account named "admin" is getting updated.  We can clear the challengeQuestion fields and run the Rest call again with a valid userName and see it fill out the questions for the admin account again.

This looks to be an issue with the underlying soap call setChallengeQuestionsOfUser. Has anyone identified a way to update the challenge questions for specific users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are going to change the challenge questions of user1, then user1 should be authenticated to call this method.

However in IS 5.1.0 alpha2, users who are having permission "/permission/admin/configure/security" can change other users' challenge questions too.

Isura